# Django - UpdateView with multi model forms - one submit

Tags: django

I'm developing the web site where users can register and edit their information. I would like to use multi form in the single page. I can develop register form using CreateView. But when I use UpdateVIew, I don't know how to add initial value in multi form.

My code(view.py) is below.  I can add `form` data as initial value, but not `form2`. Please tell me how to add `form2` data as initial value.

▪️view.py

```
class UserUpdate(OnlyYouMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    second_form_class = ProfileNearStationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/user_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET, instance=self.request.user)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET, instance=self.request.user)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form = self.form_class
        form2 = self.second_form_class
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=self.request.user)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST, instance=self.request.user)

        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
            station = form2.save(commit=False)
            station.user = user
            station.save()
            messages.success(self.request, 'Settings saved successfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
              self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return resolve_url('accounts:user_form', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

▪️form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    tel_number = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('name', 'tel_number')

class ProfileNearStationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefecture = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=areas_model.Prefecture.objects.all(), required=True)
    railway = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=areas_model.Railway.objects.none(), required=True)
    station = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=areas_model.Station.objects.none(), required=True)
    memo = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileNearStation
        fields = ('prefecture', 'railway', 'station', 'memo')
```

▪️model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tel_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProfileNearStation(models.Model):
    prefecture = models.ForeignKey(areas_model.Prefecture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    railway = models.ForeignKey(areas_model.Railway, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station = models.ForeignKey(areas_model.Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: what's the model of `ProfileNearStationForm`?

Comment: Thank you. I added `form.py`.

Comment: You're setting the `instance` of your forms to `instance=self.request.user` (which I assume is `django.contrib.auth.User` or some custom `User` model). But that's wrong. Your forms are for the `Profile` and the `ProfileNearStation` models, so you need to pass as `instance` and instance of these classes, i.e. a `profile` and `profile_near_station` object.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I don't know how to write `instance=xxx` instead of `instance=self.request.user`. please tell me..

I added `model.py`.

Comment: for `Profile` it's easy because it's a 1-to-1 field: `instance=request.user.profile`. But for `ProfileNearStation` it's impossible because one user can have many `ProfileNearStation` according to your model. So which instance should be updated?